# Java, program does only repaint() in the end

Tags: java, repaint

I have to do an assignment at school, it's a car park simulator, calling run(); from the main gives a perfectly normal simulation where the carspots get repainted every step but when calling it from an actionListener it only paints the result and not the steps inbetween. There are 6 classes down below where the main is in the Simulator class, and SimulatorView has the repaint(); in it.

So could anyone explain to me why it simulates every step when run() is called from the main, and why it just paints the output when run() is called from an ActionListener behind a JButton?

Simulator.java:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class Simulator implements ActionListener{

private CarQueue entranceCarQueue;
private CarQueue paymentCarQueue;
private CarQueue exitCarQueue;
private SimulatorView simulatorView;

private int day = 0;
private int hour = 0;
private int minute = 0;

private int tickPause = 100;

int weekDayArrivals= 50; // average number of arriving cars per hour
int weekendArrivals = 90; // average number of arriving cars per hour

int enterSpeed = 3; // number of cars that can enter per minute
int paymentSpeed = 10; // number of cars that can pay per minute
int exitSpeed = 9; // number of cars that can leave per minute

public Simulator() {
    entranceCarQueue = new CarQueue();
    paymentCarQueue = new CarQueue();
    exitCarQueue = new CarQueue();
    simulatorView = new SimulatorView(3, 6, 30, this);
}

public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        tick();
    }
}

public void run(int steps) {
    System.out.println("run " + steps + " steps");
    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        tick();
    }
}

private void tick() {
    System.out.println("simulator-tick");
    // Advance the time by one minute.
    minute++;
    while (minute > 59) {
        minute -= 60;
        hour++;
    }
    while (hour > 23) {
        hour -= 24;
        day++;
    }
    while (day > 6) {
        day -= 7;
    }

    Random random = new Random();

    // Get the average number of cars that arrive per hour.
    int averageNumberOfCarsPerHour = day < 5
            ? weekDayArrivals
            : weekendArrivals;

    // Calculate the number of cars that arrive this minute.
    double standardDeviation = averageNumberOfCarsPerHour * 0.1;
    double numberOfCarsPerHour = averageNumberOfCarsPerHour + random.nextGaussian() * standardDeviation;
    int numberOfCarsPerMinute = (int)Math.round(numberOfCarsPerHour / 60);

    // Add the cars to the back of the queue.
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCarsPerMinute; i++) {
        Car car = new AdHocCar();
        entranceCarQueue.addCar(car);
    }

    // Remove car from the front of the queue and assign to a parking space.
    for (int i = 0; i < enterSpeed; i++) {
        Car car = entranceCarQueue.removeCar();
        if (car == null) {
            break;
        }
        // Find a space for this car.
        Location freeLocation = simulatorView.getFirstFreeLocation();
        if (freeLocation != null) {
            simulatorView.setCarAt(freeLocation, car);
            int stayMinutes = (int) (15 + random.nextFloat() * 10 * 60);
            car.setMinutesLeft(stayMinutes);
        }
    }

    // Perform car park tick.
    simulatorView.tick();

    // Add leaving cars to the exit queue.
    while (true) {
        Car car = simulatorView.getFirstLeavingCar();
        if (car == null) {
            break;
        }
        car.setIsPaying(true);
        paymentCarQueue.addCar(car);
    }

    // Let cars pay.
    for (int i = 0; i < paymentSpeed; i++) {
        Car car = paymentCarQueue.removeCar();
        if (car == null) {
            break;
        }
        // TODO Handle payment.
        simulatorView.removeCarAt(car.getLocation());
        exitCarQueue.addCar(car);
    }

    // Let cars leave.
    for (int i = 0; i < exitSpeed; i++) {
        Car car = exitCarQueue.removeCar();
        if (car == null) {
            break;
        }
        // Bye!
    }

    // Update the car park view.

    simulatorView.updateView();

    // Pause.
    try {
        Thread.sleep(tickPause);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String command = e.getActionCommand();
    switch (command) {
        case "oneStep":
            run(1);
            break;
        case "hundredSteps":
            run(10);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}


public static void main (String[] args) {
    Simulator start = new Simulator();
}


}
```

SimulatorView.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class SimulatorView extends JFrame {
private CarParkView carParkView;
private int numberOfFloors;
private int numberOfRows;
private int numberOfPlaces;
private Car[][][] cars;



public SimulatorView(int numberOfFloors, int numberOfRows, int numberOfPlaces, Simulator parent) {
    this.numberOfFloors = numberOfFloors;
    this.numberOfRows = numberOfRows;
    this.numberOfPlaces = numberOfPlaces;
    cars = new Car[numberOfFloors][numberOfRows][numberOfPlaces];

    carParkView = new CarParkView();

    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    //contentPane.add(stepLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    contentPane.add(carParkView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //contentPane.add(population, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton stepForward = new JButton("oneStep");
    stepForward.addActionListener(parent);

    JButton stepHundredForward = new JButton("hundredSteps");
    stepHundredForward.addActionListener(parent);

    JMenuBar stepBar = new JMenuBar();
    stepBar.add(stepForward);
    stepBar.add(stepHundredForward);
    contentPane.add(stepBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



    pack();
    setVisible(true);

    updateView();
}



public void updateView() {
    carParkView.updateView();
}

 public int getNumberOfFloors() {
        return numberOfFloors;
    }

    public int getNumberOfRows() {
        return numberOfRows;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPlaces() {
        return numberOfPlaces;
    }

    public Car getCarAt(Location location) {
        if (!locationIsValid(location)) {
            return null;
        }
        return cars[location.getFloor()][location.getRow()][location.getPlace()];
    }

    public boolean setCarAt(Location location, Car car) {
        if (!locationIsValid(location)) {
            return false;
        }
        Car oldCar = getCarAt(location);
        if (oldCar == null) {
            cars[location.getFloor()][location.getRow()][location.getPlace()] = car;
            car.setLocation(location);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Car removeCarAt(Location location) {
        if (!locationIsValid(location)) {
            return null;
        }
        Car car = getCarAt(location);
        if (car == null) {
            return null;
        }
        cars[location.getFloor()][location.getRow()][location.getPlace()] = null;
        car.setLocation(null);
        return car;
    }

    public Location getFirstFreeLocation() {
        for (int floor = 0; floor < getNumberOfFloors(); floor++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
                for (int place = 0; place < getNumberOfPlaces(); place++) {
                    Location location = new Location(floor, row, place);
                    if (getCarAt(location) == null) {
                        return location;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Car getFirstLeavingCar() {
        for (int floor = 0; floor < getNumberOfFloors(); floor++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
                for (int place = 0; place < getNumberOfPlaces(); place++) {
                    Location location = new Location(floor, row, place);
                    Car car = getCarAt(location);
                    if (car != null && car.getMinutesLeft() <= 0 && !car.getIsPaying()) {
                        return car;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void tick() {
        System.out.println("simulatorview-tick");
        for (int floor = 0; floor < getNumberOfFloors(); floor++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
                for (int place = 0; place < getNumberOfPlaces(); place++) {
                    Location location = new Location(floor, row, place);
                    Car car = getCarAt(location);
                    if (car != null) {
                        car.tick();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean locationIsValid(Location location) {
        int floor = location.getFloor();
        int row = location.getRow();
        int place = location.getPlace();
        if (floor < 0 || floor >= numberOfFloors || row < 0 || row > numberOfRows || place < 0 || place > numberOfPlaces) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

private class CarParkView extends JPanel {

    private Dimension size;
    private Image carParkImage;    

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class CarPark
     */
    public CarParkView() {
        size = new Dimension(0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Overridden. Tell the GUI manager how big we would like to be.
     */
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 500);
    }

    /**
     * Overriden. The car park view component needs to be redisplayed. Copy the
     * internal image to screen.
     */
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (carParkImage == null) {
            return;
        }

        Dimension currentSize = getSize();
        if (size.equals(currentSize)) {
            g.drawImage(carParkImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
        else {
            // Rescale the previous image.
            g.drawImage(carParkImage, 0, 0, currentSize.width, currentSize.height, null);
        }
    }

    public void updateView() {
        // Create a new car park image if the size has changed.
        if (!size.equals(getSize())) {
            size = getSize();
            carParkImage = createImage(size.width, size.height);
        }
        Graphics graphics = carParkImage.getGraphics();
        for(int floor = 0; floor < getNumberOfFloors(); floor++) {
            for(int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
                for(int place = 0; place < getNumberOfPlaces(); place++) {
                    Location location = new Location(floor, row, place);
                    Car car = getCarAt(location);
                    Color color = car == null ? Color.white : Color.red;
                    drawPlace(graphics, location, color);
                }
            }
        }

        repaint();

    }

    /**
     * Paint a place on this car park view in a given color.
     */
    private void drawPlace(Graphics graphics, Location location, Color color) {
        graphics.setColor(color);
        graphics.fillRect(
                location.getFloor() * 260 + (1 + (int)Math.floor(location.getRow() * 0.5)) * 75 + (location.getRow() % 2) * 20,
                60 + location.getPlace() * 10,
                20 - 1,
                10 - 1); // TODO use dynamic size or constants
    }
}
}
```

Car.java:

```
public abstract class Car {

private
Location location;
private int minutesLeft;
private boolean isPaying;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Car
 */
public Car() {

}

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public int getMinutesLeft() {
    return minutesLeft;
}

public void setMinutesLeft(int minutesLeft) {
    this.minutesLeft = minutesLeft;
}

public boolean getIsPaying() {
    return isPaying;
}

public void setIsPaying(boolean isPaying) {
    this.isPaying = isPaying;
}

public void tick() {
    System.out.println("car-tick");
    minutesLeft--;
}

}
```

Location.java:

```
public class Location {

private int floor;
private int row;
private int place;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Location
 */
public Location(int floor, int row, int place) {
    this.floor = floor;
    this.row = row;
    this.place = place;
}

/**
 * Implement content equality.
 */
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof Location) {
        Location other = (Location) obj;
        return floor == other.getFloor() && row == other.getRow() && place == other.getPlace();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Return a string of the form floor,row,place.
 * @return A string representation of the location.
 */
public String toString() {
    return floor + "," + row + "," + place;
}

/**
 * Use the 10 bits for each of the floor, row and place
 * values. Except for very big car parks, this should give
 * a unique hash code for each (floor, row, place) tupel.
 * @return A hashcode for the location.
 */
public int hashCode() {
    return (floor << 20) + (row << 10) + place;
}

/**
 * @return The floor.
 */
public int getFloor() {
    return floor;
}

/**
 * @return The row.
 */
public int getRow() {
    return row;
}

/**
 * @return The place.
 */
public int getPlace() {
    return place;
}

}
```

CarQueue.java:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class CarQueue {
private Queue<Car> queue = new LinkedList<>();

public boolean addCar(Car car) {
    return queue.add(car);
}

public Car removeCar() {
    return queue.poll();
}

}
```

AdHocCar.java:

```
public class AdHocCar extends Car {
public AdHocCar() {

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @FredK & Max , fixed it by making a new thread in the actionPerformed function.

Answer (score 0):

When you call run() from the actionListener, it is being executed on the EventDispatchTread, blocking that thread until the run() method terminates. Only after that point can the EDT act on the repaint request.

Answer (score 0):

"In general Swing is not thread safe. All Swing components and related classes, unless otherwise documented, must be accessed on the event dispatching thread." [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading)

So when an action is performed, `actionListener` pick up that event and execute `run()` in the event dispatching thread.

At step 0, when it comes to `repaint()`, it doesn't draw anything because "The component will be repainted after all of the currently pending events have been dispatched." [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint(long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

The `repaint()` is waiting for the release of `ActionListener.actionPerformed`.

So it comes to step 1, the same thing happens. Only at the end, after the action event is released, the `repaint()` will be execute once. So that's why only results are there not steps in between.

My suggestion is put the painting logic in the main thread instead of the `actionListener`.